# how to retrieve environment name and its value from the string using regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell

```
str='-e ENV_PASSWORD="foo" -e ENV_USER="bar-e sd" -e ENV_DB_NAME="mysite_staging" '
```

I need to retrieve the environment variable name in one variable and its value in another from the above string using a Bash script.

I tried the below code in Python which works in python3 but the same pattern is not working with `grep`:

File: `python_test.py`

```
import re
str='-e ENV_PASSWORD="foo" -e ENV_USER="bar-e sd" -e ENV_DB_NAME="mysite_staging" '
re_pattern='-e\s+(.*?)="(.*?)"'
rec_pattern = re.compile(re_pattern, re.VERBOSE)
res = rec_pattern.findall(str)

for x in res:
  print(f'Name="{x[0]}" Value="{x[1]}"')
--------------
Output:
Name="ENV_PASSWORD" Value="foo"
Name="ENV_USER" Value="bar-e sd"
Name="ENV_DB_NAME" Value="mysite_staging"
```

File: `bash_test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
str='-e ENV_PASSWORD="foo" -e ENV_USER="bar -e sd" -e ENV_DB_NAME="mysite_staging" '
re_pattern='-e\s+(.*?)="(.*?)"'

array=( $(grep -oP $re_pattern <<<$str) )

for i in ${array[@]}; do 
    echo $i;
done
```

Comment: Kindly do post your tried code in your question, which is highly encouraged on Stack Overflow, thank you(not my downvote btw).

Comment: I have working regex in python but same is not working in bash with grep

Answer (score 2):

Storing these values in a string seems like an antipattern in the first place. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Also, notice that Python and `grep` (even with `-P`) have distinct regex dialects and facilities.

Assuming that the format of your input is fairly rigid, I would simply use the built-in regex support in Bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

str='-e ENV_PASSWORD="foo" -e ENV_USER="bar -e sd" -e ENV_DB_NAME="mysite_staging" '

re_pattern='-e[[:space:]]*([^[:space:].=]*)="([^"]*)"'

while [[ $str =~ $re_pattern ]]; do
    echo "variable: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    echo "value: ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    str=${str#*${BASH_REMATCH[1]}=\"${BASH_REMATCH[2]}\"}
done
```

The pattern contains two parenthesized groups (other than that, it's just a reformulation of your Perl pattern to traditional ERE regex) where the first captures the variable, and the second captures the value; these capture groups are collected into the Bash built-in array `BASH_REMATCH` from where we then pull them out.

This feels rather brittle (especially the parameter expansion at the end of the loop) but it works for your test case.

Demo: https://ideone.com/mY4HKI

As an aside, in your original attempt, you want `"$(array[@]}"` and `echo "$i"` with double quotes around the values; see also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

A better approach entirely would be to store the configuration in a standard machine-readable format like JSON or YAML, and take it from there.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit about the `re_pattern` you have used?

Comment: Updated the answer with a brief explanation

Answer (score -1):

Use `-E` option instead of `-P`:

```
array=( $(grep -oE $re_pattern <<<$str) )
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/lyPpal).

Comment: Their regex contains several constructs which are only supported with `-P`. It's weird that Ideone seems to accept them, but other `grep` implementation would simply fail or throw an error.

Comment: Also. the result shows that the match with a space in it is (predictably) broken up into two results.

Comment: @tripleee and yet, it works. I deliberately did not refine OP's regex, focusing only on fixing the basic problem of not using the *extended* flag.

Comment: But that's not correct. The `-P` flag is the correct one for a regex with Perl features like `\s` and `.*?`